# Changing background of table

Tags: jquery, html-helper

I'm planning to change the background of my table if the value is equal to 130 the color of the table background will be red. Here is my code  it doesn't work, so can you improve my code?

```
var computeValues = function(){
  var id = $(this)
             .attr("id")
             .replace("prelim_", "")
             .replace("midterm_","")
             .replace("final_", "");

  p = $("#prelim_" + id).val();
  m = $("#midterm_" + id).val();
  f = $("#final_" + id).val();

  Compute(p, m, f, id);

  if(p, m, f ==130) {
    $(this).css('background-color','red');          
  }

};
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: then where is the problem coming?

Comment: i doesnt work  ...is my code okay?

Comment: I guess something here can be a problem if(p, m, f ==130)...you can write like this if (p==130 &&m==130 &&f==130)

Comment: thanks @Darshan but my problem now it only colors its only column so i need the whole table to be filled with colors

Comment: That may be because $(this) is referring to that particular cell. How do you call computeValues()?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$(this)` is not defined where you used it because you aren't inside of jQuery's callback function scope:

```
$(this).css('background-color','red');
```

Also, this `if` statement may be evaluating to `false` if `f` is not equal to `130`:

```
if(p, m, f ==130)
```